# Bug? Cannot set persistent booleans without managed policy

Tags: apache, email, redhat

I have an installation of Magneto, and it couldn't send any emails. Upon investigation, `httpd_can_sendmail` was turned off. This can be shown by `getsebool -a | grep mail`.

First I tried `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on`, which gave me an error `Cannot set persistent booleans without managed policy`.

Then I read [this article](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=666365), and it's saying this is a bug and that it should really complain that you need root privileges. So `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on` turned it on.. The bug report is 4 years old, and this site is on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) hosted on AWS. Is this error message simply just mis-worded? Should I have run that command as `root`?

Answer (score 0):

this error message is right, because you need to have a privileged user to set selinux Properties.

If you not need to be privileged user, every user on the system can change selinux and so things you dont want.

I hope this answer is useful for you.

Comment: OP is asking about the "managed policy" message, not about privileged access.

Comment: Is this error message simply just mis-worded? Should I have run that command as root? So he asked about privileged user, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to root did indeed clear the problem for me.